# How do I click a link inside the frame using robot framework selenium2Library?

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, selenium2library

Below is my code, I could login to the page but after logging in I am not able to log out.

Maximize Browser Window

```
Input Text    //*[@id="userid"]    some_user_name
Input Password    //*[@id="password"]    some_password 
Click Button    //*[@id="btnSubmit"]
sleep    10s
Select Frame    //*[@id="topFrame"]
Page Should Contain    Log out
Click Element    //*[contains(text(),'Log out')]
```

Logs:

```
Starting test: WebScraping.NAS web.Welcome
20191009 15:29:40.801 : INFO : Opening browser 'chrome' to base url 'some url'.
20191009 15:29:45.557 : INFO : Typing text '******' into text field '//*[@id="userid"]'.
20191009 15:29:45.658 : INFO : Typing password into text field '//*[@id="password"]'.
20191009 15:29:45.739 : INFO : Clicking button '//*[@id="btnSubmit"]'.
20191009 15:29:55.823 : INFO : Slept 10 seconds
20191009 15:29:55.881 : INFO : Current page contains text 'Log out'.
20191009 15:29:55.881 : INFO : Clicking element '//*[contains(text(),'Log out')]'.
20191009 15:29:56.310 : FAIL : Element with locator '//*[contains(text(),'Log out')]' not found.
Ending test: WebScraping.NAS web.Welcome
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the following line:

```
Select Frame    //*[@id="topFrame"]
```

The frame tag does not contain the id attribute, instead it uses the name attribute to be identified. ([HTML  Tag Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp))

Use @name instead @id, as in the following line

```
Select Frame    //*[@name="topFrame"]
```

I hope this solves your problem.